# Strange behaviour on postback in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I'm working on a website with a login form. To log in, a postback is used to an OnClick handler in the codebehind.
Somehow, the value returned from the Text-property of the username and password textboxes is ten times the value I entered, separated by commas. I checked my entire code for double ID's (which seems to be the most common problem causing this behaviour), but I found each ID defined only once.

In the ASPX file I have this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFeedback" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Visible="false" /><br />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server">
            <table style="border-style: none;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" AssociatedControlID="txtUsername" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" /><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="password" /><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
```

The OnClick handler in the Codebehind:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Util.Escape(txtUsername.Text);
        string password = Util.Escape(txtPassword.Text);

        WebsiteUser user = WebsiteUser.Create(username, password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            //Set some session variables and redirect to user profile
        }
        else
        {
            lblFeedback.Text = Localizer.Translate("INVALID_LOGIN");
            lblFeedback.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblFeedback.Visible = true;
            pnlLogin.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The website is running on ASP.NET 2.0 on ISS 5.1 (Win XP Pro)

Comment: Hmm, that looks correct and okay. Can you post the code for class WebsiteUser including the Create(string,string) method? Are there any database procedures or inserts called? Post those too, please?

Comment: I'd like to see `Page_Load`, sounds like there may be some ungated work work happening there (IE, not wrapped in `if (Page.IsPostback) { }`)

Comment: Do you see the bad values before or after you call Utils.Escape (could the problem be in the Escape method)?

Comment: Along the lines of Johns comment, are you using ajax on this page?

Comment: Have you tried removing some of the utils related functions for testing purposes?  Try passing in the text from the textboxes directly instead of escaping to see if any unknown string manipulation is occuring there

Comment: This section of code wouldn't happen to be nested in a Ajax Control Toolkit modal popup, would it?

Comment: I'm not using ASP.NET Ajax, only custom Ajax handling via jQuery and ASP.NET IHttpHandlers. But then again, the only part of the site I'm not using Ajax at all is with logging in.   

If I don't use the Escape method, the result is the same, and in my Page_Load I only set the text on the labels in pnlLogin.  

I've changed the implementation though, using yamspog's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code all looks okay.  Some of the things that I would consider is your Util.Escape function.  You could use HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode if you are concerned about malicious entry.  You could also go with the asp:login control as it provides all the features you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. The Escape method shouldn't be the problem, I've used it in several other projects, including now with the ASP:Login control.